# unregistered task type import errors in celery

Tags: celery

I'm having headaches with getting celery to work with my folder structure. Note I am using virtualenv but it should not matter.

```
cive /
    celery_app.py
    __init__.py
    venv
    framework /
        tasks.py
        __init__.py
        civeAPI /
            files tasks.py need
```

cive is my root project folder.

celery_app.py:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import

from celery import Celery

app = Celery('cive',
         broker='amqp://',
         backend='amqp://',
         include=['cive.framework.tasks'])

# Optional configuration, see the application user guide.
app.conf.update(
    CELERY_TASK_RESULT_EXPIRES=3600,
)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.start()
```

tasks.py (simplified)

```
from __future__ import absolute_import  
#import other things
#append syspaths
from cive.celery_app import app  

@app.task(ignore_result=False)
def start(X):
    # do things

def output(X):
    # output files

def main():
    for d in Ds:
        m = []
        m.append( start.delay(X) )
        output( [n.get() for n in m] )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv[1:]))
```

I then start workers via (outside root cive dir)

```
celery -A cive worker --app=cive.celery_app:app -l info
```

which seems to work fine, loading the workers and showing

```
[tasks]
  . cive.framework.tasks.start_sessions
```

But when I try to run my tasks.py via another terminal:

```
python tasks.py
```

I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tasks.py", line 29, in <module>
    from cive.celery_app import app
ImportError: No module named cive.celery_app
```

If I rename the import to:

```
from celery_app import app #without the cive.celery_app
```

I can eventually start the script but celery returns error:

```
Received unregistered task of type 'cive.start_sessions'
```

I think there's something wrong with my imports or config but I can't say what.

Answer (score 0):

So this was a python package problem, not particularly a celery issue. I found the solution by looking at [How to fix "Attempted relative import in non-package" even with __init__.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11536764/attempted-relative-import-in-non-package-even-with-init-py) .

I've never even thought about this before, but I wasn't running python in package mode. The solution is cd'ing out of your root project directory, then running python as a package (note there is no .py after tasks):

```
 python -m cive.framework.tasks
```

Now when I run the celery task everything works.